# How to center horizontally 2 or more UIViews inside a UIView container using autolayout programmatically in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

I'm trying to center 2 or more `UIView`s horizontally inside a `UIView` e.g.

```
|             [UIView1] [UIView2]             |
|        [UIView1] [UIView2] [UIView3]        |
```

or

```
|   [UIView1] [UIView2] [UIView3] [UIView4]   |
```

I'm adding these constraints to all the views inside the container view

```
let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: views[N], attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: container, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: views[N], attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: container, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: views[N], attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: width)
let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: views[N], attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: height)
```

And I'm adding a spacing constraints between each view

```
let spacingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: views[N], attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: views[N+1], attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
```

The above constraints horizontally center all views.

If I change the priority of the `horizontalConstraint` to 750 then I'm getting something like this

[image: odd number]

[image: even number]

As you can see, when I have an odd number of views these will be horizontally aligned properly, but this is not the case when having an even number of views.

How can I center horizontally any even number of views inside and another view programmatically without using another container or spacing views?

Comment: I don't know whether you decided completely to write constraints programmatically if you use stack view, it will fulfill your requirement with ease.

Comment: Can you provide and example using stack view done programmatically that can solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was able to accomplish this with the help of the `UIStackView`as recommended by @Sivajee Battina and @Nedim. I created a `UIStackView` property and the setup the views as follow

```
    self.view.addSubview(container)
    labelContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    container.addSubview(stackContainer)
    stackContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackContainer.axis =  .horizontal
    stackContainer.distribution = .equalSpacing
    stackContainer.alignment = .bottom
    stackContainer.spacing = spacing
```

Then I added the constraint as follow

```
    container.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 10.0).isActive = true
    container.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 10.0).isActive = true
    container.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: -10.0).isActive = true
    container.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: containerWidth).isActive = true
    container.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: containerHeight).isActive = true

    stackContainer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    stackContainer.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    for view in self.views {
        view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewWidth).isActive = true
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewHeight).isActive = true
    }
```

Resulting in the solution!!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should use `UIStackView`. If you don't know how to use `UIStackView` you can check out [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views) tutorial.

Here's how stack views should look alike.

[image: Adding StackViews]

Keep in mind that in attributes inspector of Stack View you need to enter Axis.

[image: Attributes Inspector (StackView)]

Anyway, if you still want to add constraints programmatically, I recommend using [SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit#usage).

Here's an example how to use it:

```
let box = UIView()
let container = UIView()

container.addSubview(box)

box.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
    make.size.equalTo(50)
    make.center.equalTo(container)
}
```

As you can see, there is much less code with SnapKit.

Comment: Will read more about the `UIStackView` I need the solution to be programmatically as the views are added dynamic.